# OpenCL Write __global variable

Tags: opencl

I would like to have a Variable with Read-Access to all kernels/functions inside a CL Program. For this i have created a variable at the top of the File and prefixed it with __global.

```
typedef struct{
    /* whatever */
}  GlobalParameters;

__global GlobalParameters params;
```

how can i set the Values inside that Struct from the Host code now? Is that even Possible, or how can i edit it else? Or do i have to pass it as Parameter to the kernel every time i need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Program scope variables are meant to be constants and need to be initialized.

So, this works like:

```
typedef struct{
    float whatever;
}  GlobalParameters;

__constant GlobalParameters params=(GlobalParameters){3.14f};
```

then you can use it anywhere. But if opencl-compile-time is ok for it, you can alter it with string replacement after preaparing the host-side constant buffer:

```
typedef struct{
    float whatever;
}  GlobalParameters;

__constant GlobalParameters params=(GlobalParameters){##replace_0##};
```

if this is used for minutes per change, you can re-compile it using new string replacement before device-kernel-compiling. If there are non-changing sets, you can compile N times for different kernel programs and switch between them using different contexts.